# How do I get a detailed vista bootlog?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, log-files, boot

How can I get a detailed report of what/when things are getting loaded during vista boot?

The basic reports found in the event viewer are @ too high of a level. Someone must've needed more information before.

Answer (score 4):

Press F8 during the Vista boot, choose "Enable Boot Logging" from the menu, and then boot Vista. You'll find, in the %SystemRoot% directory (normally C:\WINDOWS) a boot log file "ntbtlog.txt".

Answer (score 0):

The way Microsoft wants you to inspect the boot process in full detail:
http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/speed-up-boot-time-in-windows-vista/

You can get those tools from your Windows SDK or in the bottom right at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/default.aspx

> Using these tools, you can capture and analyze a wide array of performance problems such as boot issues, start up times, DPCs and ISRs, application resource usage, and system responsiveness.
>
> The reason why you can get so much detailed information about the boot up process using these tools is because they are built using the Event Tracing for Windows infrastructure.
>
> Hopefully these tools will help you figure out why your computer is booting up slowly, shutting down slowly, or having problems with Standby and Hibernate. Enjoy!

Comment: The link given is no longer available. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/default.aspx